# Cropping image with CIImage.ImageByCroppingToRect or CICrop in MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, crop

I have a very large image that I would like to show a 200x200px thumbnail of (showing a portion of the image, not a strethed version of the entire image). To achieve this I am looking into using CIImage.ImageByCroppingToRect or CICrop - but I am not able to get anything useful. Either the result is just black (I assume what I see is the black portion of the cropped image) or I get a SIGABRT ("Cannot handle a (6000 x 3000) sized texture with the given GLES context!")

There is a ObjC sample in this thread:
[Cropping CIImage with CICrop isn't working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601242/cropping-ciimage-with-cicrop-isnt-working-properly)

But I haven't managed to translate it in to C# and get it working properly.

Comment: I am confused. I thought this was an iPhone question, but you want a C# solution?

Comment: @Jeshua - MonoTouch is a C# framework for iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a MonoTouch port of the answer from the post you mentioned:

```
var croppedImaged = CIImage.FromCGImage (inputCGImage).ImageByCroppingToRect (new RectangleF (150, 150, 300, 300));              
var transformFilter = new CIAffineTransform();
var affineTransform = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation (-150, 150);
transformFilter.Transform = affineTransform;
transformFilter.Image = croppedImaged;           
CIImage transformedImage = transformFilter.OutputImage;
```

Comment: Thank you! That code indeed works - unless the image you want cropped is larger than 4096x4096 because than the SIGABRT will come. Not sure wether that is a limitation in iOS, MonoTouch, iPhone Simulator or just my computer...

Comment: This is a limitation of the GPU on the device.   You can avoid using the GPU by requesting the software renderer in your CIContext construction: CIContext.FromOptions (new CIContextOptions () { UseSoftwareRenderer = true })

Comment: Thank you Miguel, but that actually returns null instead of a valid CIContext (at least on the Simulator - I haven't tried with an actual device yet).