# How to crop image with particular position and set to another view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Crop image from particular position and set to another view

**Final image view**

```
self.finalImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 320)];
if(rectangle_button_preesed_view)
{
    self.finalImageView.image =[self croppIngimageByImageName:self.imageView.image toRect:CGRectMake(30, 120, 260, 340)];
}
else
{
    self.finalImageView.image =[self croppIngimageByImageName:self.imageView.image toRect:CGRectMake(30, 80, 260, 260)];
}
```

**Cropping image**

```
- (UIImage *)croppIngimageByImageName:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    NSLog(@" cropped size %f %f ",cropped.size.width,cropped.size.height);
    return cropped;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@implementation UIImage (Crop)

- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)cropRect {

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], cropRect);
    UIImage *cropedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return cropedImage;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);
// or use the UIImage wherever you like
[UIImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

OR

```
@implementation UIImage (Crop)

- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect {

    rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x*self.scale, 
                      rect.origin.y*self.scale, 
                      rect.size.width*self.scale, 
                      rect.size.height*self.scale);       

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef 
                                          scale:self.scale 
                                    orientation:self.imageOrientation]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside `CoreGraphics` solution, I would also suggest to use `CoreImage` which support filters for image manipulation. You should look at `CICrop` filter found in [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CICrop).

**Note:** This filter is supported for iOS 5 or greater.

I currently do not have an exact solution but you can go ahead with [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601242/cropping-ciimage-with-cicrop-isnt-working-properly).

Hope it helps!